# Is there a way to render Partial Views in WebForms?

Tags: asp.net-3.5, webforms

I'm touching an old `WebForms project` but I'm long gone from it and I'm now to used to MVC. I'm trying to refractor the project and come up with a simple issue that is making me crazy...

What would be the best way to include an `.aspx` file within another?

I don't want to end up having a lot of Master Files just for this, all I'm after is something like `@Html.RenderPartial("MyFileName")` kind'a thingy or

> it's that hard to include a file in some existing files?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `UserControl` [Tutorial on UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). They are files with `.ascx` extension and you can include them in your pages

```
//UserControl1.ascx
<% @ Control Language="C#" ClassName="UserControl1" %>

 <div>
   My Custom Control: I can use any Server controls, html tags etc
 </div>
```

Include it in your `.aspx` page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="MyCustomControl" Src="~/Controls/UserControl1.ascx" %>
<html>
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <uc:MyCustomControl id="MyPartialView" 
        runat="server" />
</form>
</body>
```